# How to thread a function from an imported library?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I've been working on a Python program but the syntax of Python is still relatively new to me. For example, if I have two Python files with the contents below, what's the proper way to thread the function?

main.py - this is the file being executed

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#threading array
threads = []

import threading
import anotherFile as af

afCheck = af.init() #return true or false
if afCheck == True: 
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=af.listener))

try:
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print("closing up shop");
    for thread in threads:
        thread.cancel()
    sys.exit()
```

I was going to write up some dummy code for anotherFile.py, but it seems pretty inconsequential. I've been able to test this to the point that I've seen that it isn't executing the listener and I'm not sure the proper way to call it.

Maybe I just need to thread the listener inside of anotherFile.py, but thought for simplicities sake, it would be nice to have them all in one place since this will have multiple imports.

Comment: So anotherFile needs to have the functions init() and listener(). Away from that your code looks okay.

Comment: Indeed, so what's your question exactly?

Comment: I can't test on my current machine since this relies on some specific hardware not shown in the same, but I believe the issue wasn't related to addressing the listener. I'll test this tonight and remove this post. Thanks for the help regardless. Like I said, the syntax is all new to me, so it sucks knowing things can be done, just not how to do them exactly!!